# create my_robot.urdf file?

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the tutorial:

**wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Create your own urdf file**

In which directory do I have to create my_robot.urdf file?

I created in my home directory (mudassar) and it did not successfully execute following commands:

*rosmake urdfdom_model*

*check_urdf my_robot.urdf # hydro*

Could you please guide the possible reason?

MY ros is hydro and I am using ubuntu 12.04LTS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125331/create-my_robot.urdf-file?/) by [mudassar](https://answers.ros.org/users/10726/mudassar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2014-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-02-01**:
execute check_urdf  in the directory where you had my_robot.urdf file.

**Comment by [mudassar](https://answers.ros.org/users/10726/mudassar/) on 2014-02-01**:
Actually I did the same but did not work for me!

**Comment by [mudassar](https://answers.ros.org/users/10726/mudassar/) on 2014-02-03**:
Thankyou! Issue resolved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

use "rosrun urdfdom check_urdf my_robot.urdf"

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0